# Navigation bar is overlap by horizontal scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have horizontal scroll buttons which will navigate to another view controller when a user selects the button which is working fine but the problem arises when user tap back button, navigationbar is been hidden.

It looks like the horizontal scroll buttons are overlapping the navigation bar. I have written those scroll buttons programmatically.

Comment: Where is the buttons being added? To which view.

Comment: You need to provide more information, relevant code, possibly screenshots. Try reading your question as if you had no idea about your problem.

Comment: @MartinBorstrand - Buttons are added  to homeVC just below the navigation bar. it can be scroll horizontally.

Comment: Need more information otherwise it is very hard to provide any solution.

Comment: You have to show us your code, otherwise this will be impossible.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the back button action is implemented wrong. As commented above I would need to see more code to really help.

Answer (score 0):

```
HomeVC.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface HomeVC : 
  UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
- (IBAction)buttonClicked1:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)buttonClicked2:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)unWindHomeVC:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue;

-(void) imageTaped;

- (IBAction)myProflBtn:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)myContactBtn:(id)sender;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tablezView1;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *devices;

@end
```

HomeVC.m

```
#import "HomeVC.h"
#import "AddInfoVC.h"
#import "MyProfileTableViewCell.h"
#import "SuperObject.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"






@interface HomeVC ()



{

NSManagedObjectContext *context;

NSIndexPath *selectIndexPath;


}

@end

int j;

@implementation HomeVC


@synthesize tablezView1;
@synthesize tableView2;
@synthesize devices;




- (void)viewDidLoad
{


[super viewDidLoad];


AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *) [UIApplication 
sharedApplication].delegate;

context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext;




}




-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {


NSMutableArray *arrImage = [NSMutableArray 
arrayWithObjects:@"Recovery.png", 
@"Fire.png",@"police.png",@"Hospital1.png",@"blood.png",nil];


UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] 
initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,60, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];




int x = 0;
CGRect frame;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    if (i == 0) {
        frame = CGRectMake(10, 25, 45, 45);
    } else {
        frame = CGRectMake((i * 80) + (i * 20) + 10, 25, 45, 45);
    }

    button.frame = frame;
    button.tag=i;

    NSString *butimage=arrImage[i];

    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:butimage];

    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)button.tag);

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [scrollView addSubview:button];

    if (i == 4)
    {

        x = CGRectGetMaxX(button.frame);
    }

}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollView.frame.size.height);

scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

}

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];



NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Opositive"];

devices = [context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:nil];

[tablezView1 reloadData];



















}




-(void)imageTapped:(id)sender
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;

NSLog(@"tapped!");
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)button.tag);

switch(button.tag)
{
    case 0 :
    {
        NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RecoveryVC"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
        break;
    case 1 :{


        NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FireServiceVC"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
        break;
    case 2 :
    {
        NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PoliceStationVC"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

        break;
    case 3 :
    {
        NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HospitalVC"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }break;
    case 4 :
    {
        NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BloodDonationVC"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    } break;
```

}

}

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{


if(tableView == self.tablezView1){

    return devices.count;

}
else if (tableView == self.tableView2){

    return 5;
}
return 0;
```

}

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
if (tableView == self.tablezView1){


    static NSString *cellIdentifier1 = @"MyProfileTVCell";

    MyProfileTableViewCell *cell1 = (MyProfileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier1];

    if (cell1 == nil){

    NSArray *nib1 =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyProfileTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        cell1 = [nib1 objectAtIndex:0];

    }






    NSManagedObject *mangedObj = [devices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell1.prfNmeLbel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Profilename:%@",[mangedObj valueForKey:@"opositivename"]];



    cell1.prfCntLbel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ProfileContactNo:%@", [mangedObj valueForKey:@"opositivecontactno"]];


    cell1.prfCtyLbel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ProfileCity:%@", [mangedObj valueForKey:@"opositivecity"]];



    cell1.prfAddresLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ProfileAddress:%@", [mangedObj valueForKey:@"opositivecaddress"]];



    cell1.prfCountryLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ProfileCountry:%@", [mangedObj valueForKey:@"opositivecountry"]];









    return cell1;


}

if (tableView == self.tableView2){

    static NSString *cellIdentifier2 = @"CommonTVC";

    CommonTVC *cell2 = (CommonTVC *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier2];

    if (cell2 == nil){

        NSArray *nib2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommonTVC" owner:self options:nil];
        cell2 = [nib2 objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell2;
}


return 0;
```

}

```
-(BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


if (indexPath.row %2 == 0){


    return YES;

}


return NO;
```

}

```
- (IBAction)addInfoButton:(id)sender {
```

AddInfoVC *DishItemList=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddInfoVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:DishItemList animated:YES];
    }

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked1:(id)sender {

UIStoryboard *storyboardObj = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

AddInfoVC *addInfoObj = [storyboardObj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddInfoVC"];

[self presentViewController:addInfoObj animated:NO completion:nil];










}
```

- (IBAction)buttonClicked2:(id)sender {

  UIStoryboard *storyboardObj = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

  OptionVC *optObj = [storyboardObj instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OptionVC"];

  [self presentViewController:optObj animated:NO completion:nil];

}

```
- (IBAction)unWindHomeVC:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{


HomeVC *sourceVC = segue.sourceViewController;

if([sourceVC isKindOfClass:[AddInfoVC class]]){



    NSLog(@"Coming from AddInfo");

}


 if([sourceVC isKindOfClass:[ProfileVC class]]) {

     NSLog(@"Coming from ProfileVC");
}


if ([sourceVC isKindOfClass:[MyContactsVC class]]){

    NSLog(@"Coming from MyContacts");
}
```

}

```
- (IBAction)myProflBtn:(id)sender {


NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    ProfileVC *profile = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProfileVC"];

    profile.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;

    [self presentViewController:profile animated:YES completion:nil];


    // configure the popover presentation controller

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [profile popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;

     popController.delegate = self;


    popController.sourceView = self.view;
    popController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(30, 50, 10, 10);




}




- (IBAction)myContactBtn:(id)sender {


    NSString *storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    MyContactsVC *contact = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyContactsVC"];

    contact.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    [self presentViewController:contact animated:YES completion:nil];

    // configure the popover presentation controller

    UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = [contact popoverPresentationController];
    popController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp;
    popController.delegate = self;

    // In case we don't have a  bar button as reference

    popController.sourceView = self.view;
    popController.sourceRect = CGRectMake(30, 50, 10, 10);




}















@end
```